# Paste N from VBA to cell, when N is dim N as integer, N = N+1

Tags: vba, excel

I´m a rookie in VBA and have used this site to find answers before, but here is a question I havn´t found an answer to yet.
I have 20 workbooks whitch I´m opening and running using my master workbook. In this workbook I insert the numbers from 1 to 25. But I get the error "Invalid Qualifier" when i try to run the macro.
Here is the bit in my code where which is marked when i get the error: intDistrikt.Paste

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Dim strMåned As String, intDistrikt As Integer, rngStart As Range, intNumRow As Integer
Dim intX As Integer, intLoops As Integer, lstMåned As UserForm
intDistrikt = 0    

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do
    intDistrikt = intDistrikt + 1
    Windows("Lønudvikling.xlsm").Select
    Range("C5").Select
    **intDistrikt.Paste**

    Application.Run "'Lønudvikling.xlsm'!DistriktsLønopfølgning"

    Range("B10:H24").Copy
    Windows("Kæde lønudvikling.xlsx").Select
    Sheets("Kæde").Select
    rngStart.Select
    Range.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Loop Until intDistrikt >= 25
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you not want to just put the value of `intDistrikt` into cell C5? In which case it would be

`Range("C5").Value = intDistrikt`